# stop node application using gradle

Tags: node.js, gradle

I am using [Gradle Node Plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) to start my `angular2` based application using `gradle`.

Configuration looks like this

```
node {
    version="7.7.4"
    distBaseUrl="https://nodejs.org/dist"
    download="true"
    workDir=file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")
    nodeModulesDir=file("${project.projectDir}")
}
```

When I start it using `gradle npm_start` it loads application just fine.

However to stop I use `CTRL+C` and then I have to go to open Task Manager and stop `node` processes.

What is the proper way to stop application without need to use `task manager`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way change it, except create `gradle.properties` file on the same level with the `build.gradle` and adding record: `org.gradle.daemon=false`, [opened issue](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/143). Without daemon usage, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is on angoing bug in Gradle itself ([link](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7603)). The authors of the Gradle Node plugin have their own bug report to fix it on their side whenever Gradle is updated ([link](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/issues/65)).